# Github Action - Reusable workflow AND manual trigger

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm surprised that I haven't seen this asked anywhere (unless my googlefu is not as strong as I thought!)

I'm trying to get a reusable workflow only to run if manually triggered, even after being called by the caller workflow.

Here are a few examples of how I thought it **should** work:

**Caller Workflow**

```
name: Calling reusable workflow
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - release
      - develop
      - main

jobs:
  call-workflow:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reusable-workflow1.yaml
    secrets: inherit
```

**Reusable workflow**

```
name: Reusable Workflow
on:
  workflow_call:
    secrets:
      secret_1:
        description: The Environment secret for secret_1
        required: true
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      test_choice:
        type: choice
        description: "Select a choice"
        required: true
        options: 
          - Test1
          - Test2
          - Test3

env:
  GITHUB_RUN_ID: $GITHUB_RUN_ID

jobs:
  log-the-inputs:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo "Choice: $choice"
          echo "Secret: $secret"
          echo "GitHub Run ID: $GITHUB_RUN_ID"
        env:
          choice: ${{ inputs.test_choice }}
          secret: ${{ secrets.secret_1 }}
```

So when testing, once the main caller workflow is started, it just calls the reusable workflow right away, which as you can expect will fail due to it not having the `inputs.choice` as it hasn't asked for it as part of the manual trigger.

Has anyone found a way to do this at all/if this is even possible?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you expect the behaviour to be. If you don't pass the `test_choice` input (which, by the way, you reference by the wrong name, `choice` instead of `test_choice`) when you call the reusable workflow, it's not there. You have to pass it from the caller workflow.

Comment: Hey @BenjaminW., thats my bad there, yeah I didn't put in the correct `inputs.test_choice` on the var there. Ill update that now. But the main point still stands in that I want the reusable workflow to be able to be manually triggered after being called by the caller workflow. At that point is where I would select the choice of the 3 options and it would feed it into the workflow

Comment: Ah, I don't think that's possible. You have to provide all inputs for every trigger. `workflow_call` doesn't know anything about other triggers in the same workflow.

Comment: It should be possible now as announced in https://github.blog/changelog/2022-06-10-github-actions-inputs-unified-across-manual-and-reusable-workflows/